Android emulator failed to start. Failed to process .ini file
I am getting the following warning when trying to start my android emulator
Failed to process .ini file C:\Users\shopr\.android\avd\..\avd\Nexus_S_API_25.avd\quickbootChoice.ini for reading. error on emulator start.
I am working on AMD processor 7535HS with SVM enabled.

I have checked boot option and SVM is already enabled. I have also selected emulator graphics as Software.


Can you identify which version of emulator you are running and have the appropriate Windows setting: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
